# Can a buildType be referenced in multiple subprojects in TeamCity Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

Is there a way to have, in a project, a buildType referenced in two separate subprojects?  That is, have buildType A registered in subproject B and also appearing in subproject C?

Perhaps something like the following?

```
object Project : Project ({
    
    subProject {
        id("B")
        buildType {
            id("A")
        }
    }
    subProject {
        id("C")
        <reference to buidType B.A>
    }
})
```

As far as I can tell, the Kotlin DSL [Project](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/dsl-documentation/root/project/index.html) class only supports registering buildTypes, it does not support referencing buildTypes that are already registered.  And a buildType can only be registered once (with the same id).

If it were possible to have references to registered buildTypes, it would allow multiple ways of organizing projects with large numbers of build configurations.